# How to clear HTML File Input field (while using fakeupload) in IE?

Tags: php, function, file-upload

We are using this [solution](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/inputfile.html) to style our "browse" buttons. However, when we use this technique, our "clear" button no longer works in IE. In other words, it doesn't remove the fakepath. Still works in Firefox and Chrome though.

```
<div id="upload_div">
  <li class="uploadlink">
    <div class="fakeupload">
     <input type="text" name="fakeupload" />
    </div>

  <input type="file" name="upload" id="uploadFile" class="realupload" onchange="this.form.fakeupload.value = this.value;"/>     
  <input name="clearinput" type="button" value="Clear" onClick="clearFileInput('upload_div')">                
  </li> 
</div>
```

Clear button function:

```
function clearFileInput(tagId) { 
    document.getElementById(tagId).innerHTML = document.getElementById(tagId).innerHTML; 
}
```